# Java For loop and polymorphism

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, polymorphism

I was wondering how I could handle polymorphism in a for loop without using of "instanceof" like in C#.
Here is what I have :

An abstract class A :

```
public abstract class A
{
    public abstract Map<Long, ? extends A> getNodes();
    public abstract void setNodes(Map<Long, ? extends A> n);
}
```

B and C classes which extends A and implements abstract methods of A :

```
public class B
{
    private Map<Long, C> childNodesC;

    @Override
    public Map<Long, ? extends A> getNodes()
    {
        return childNodesC;
    }

    @Override
    public void setNodes(Map<Long, ? extends A> n)
    {
        for(C child : n)
            childNodesC.put(child.getId(), child);
    }
}
```

Is a for-loop like this one in setNodes() method, possible in Java ? I mean, is there a way for Java to understand that, in my loop, I want to iterate only over all C objects in a list of A objects (which here could be either B or C objects).

Or maybe I don't use polymorphism in the right way or something like that...or maybe this is a true case of "instanceof" operator usage :)

(Yeah you're right, I don't like "instanceof" operator, it makes me think that I didn't do the things correctly so I need to fix them with casts and instanceof. It looks "dirty" to me, but maybe I'm wrong and it is very common to use it !)

Thanks !

Comment: It does look a bit wrong to use `instanceof`.  But I think the whole design looks a bit wrong here:  it won't be obvious to users that `setNodes(nodes)` of B actually ignores some of the given nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are sometimes cases where you need to know of which subclass an instance is. We can't really determine if your case is one of those. But if you need to implement this you should consider using the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and only implement the method of your wanted subclass. This way you avoid the 'dirty' instanceof checks.

Answer (score 1):

That sort of loop-and-filter isn't available in Java. As for whether you're using polymorphism correctly, it's hard to say without a bit more context. If `B.childNodesC` needs to use a method that isn't available on `A`, then you probably need to just use `instanceof` to filter out the `C`s. But otherwise, a more purely OO approach would be to define a method on `A` that answers some filtering question, and then have `B`'s map have `A` values. Something like:

```
A.isSomethingInteresting() -> false
A.doSomething() { ... }
C.isSomethingInteresting() -> true
C.doSomething() overrides { ... }
```

B.setNodes would then see if each A is something interesting, and add it to its map only if it does. It would then invoke `doSomething()` on each of its `A`s, and polymorphism would take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

That sort of construct is not possible in Java (at least through Java 6). That loop expects every object to be an instance of C and does not act as a filter (and it should not). In general, if you are looping through something you want to get everything. If you want to further filter, then that's a separate action. There is no shame in using `instanceof` to do that (any more than there is shame in checking a property of an object).